# MySql Query value can be null

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `Products` 
 WHERE brand REGEXP '$brandFilter' 
   AND categories REGEXP '$categoryFilter' 
   AND color REGEXP '$colorFilter' 
   AND price BETWEEN '$priceMin' AND '$priceMax' 
   AND size REGEXP '$sizeFilter'
```

I work with PHP and every value obtained can be empty
It is possible to check in SQL if the value is empty?
for example: if '$brandFilter' is not null

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Products
 WHERE brand REGEXP '$brandFilter'
```

It is possible to do this in code but it is very long because it is possible to get 3 values null

thanks for your help!

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQL perspective, you need `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE (brand      REGEXP :brandFilter    OR :brandFilter    IS NULL)
  AND (categories REGEXP :categoryFilter OR :categoryFilter IS NULL)
  AND (color      REGEXP :colorFilter    OR :colorFilter    IS NULL)
  ...
```

You might want to dynamically build the `where` clause in your application, which would probably make for more efficient SQL code.

Note that this uses bind parameters rather that concatenating variables in the query string. Recommended reading: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716).